# Dropbox download not working in Hello.js

Tags: javascript, hello.js

{
  "read_only": false,
  "revision": 163,
  "bytes": 50459,
  "thumb_exists": true,
  "rev": "a341d3afbb",
  "modified": "Sun, 28 Feb 2016 15:08:41 +0000",
  "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
  "size": "49.3 KB",
  "path": "/undefined/girl.jpg",
  "is_dir": false,
  "modifier": null,
  "root": "dropbox",
  "client_mtime": "Sun, 28 Feb 2016 15:08:41 +0000",
  "icon": "page_white_picture",

"type": "image/jpeg",
  "name": "girl.jpg",
  "downloadLink": "http://localhost:5500/proxy?path=https%3A%2F%2Fapi-content.dropbox.com%2F1%2Ffiles%2Fauto%2Fdropbox%2Fundefined%2Fgirl.jpg&access_token=ccpsw20fvhoac9g2:cibllca6q9vr2m5@27hvto4ucs4y8mw",
    "id": "undefined/girl.jpg"
}

this is the json response i get when i use api() function of hello.js
here is the function i call on onclick event
function getName(network){

```
        hello("dropbox").api('me/files', 'get',{
            path: "/undefined/girl.jpg",
        }).then(function(json){
                log(json);
        }, function(e){
            alert('errrr ! '+ e.error.message);
        });

    return false;
}
```

but when i copy the downloadLink from the json response and run it through postman i get {"error": "File not found"}

The actual question is that can I download a resourse from dropbox through hello.js?
if I can then how??
Note:running oauth-shim on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Is that `http://localhost:5500/proxy?path=` really in the Dropbox response?  This means you are accessing the API through a proxy server and that's rewriting their response.  If you were to strip that off and urldecode the rest, it should work - but you really need to figure out why your request is going through a proxy server and solve that.

Comment: i am using hello.js https://adodson.com/hello.js/ thats why my request have a proxy in it. i want to use hello.js in my mean stack applicaton.